# npm start does nothing while the command works properly when using NodeJS with Express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

#### UPDATE:

I had nvm for windows installed and forgot about it. It was projecting the contents of its node installation to the program files folder.

#### ORIGINAL:

So I have a very simple project [copied from freecodecamp](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/nodejs/express/)

**`index.js`**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "test-app", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "", "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [], "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Running `node index.js` starts the server and operates as expected, but if I run `npm start` it just returns:

```
> test-app@1.0.0 start D:\temp\test-app
> node index.js

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.885]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

and exits out.

I would expect that `npm start` does the same thing as `node index.js` since it uses the same command, as described [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introduction-to-npm-scripts-1dbb2ae01633/).

What did I do wrong?

I have tried:

1. running `npm cache clean --force`
2. removing node_modules and running `npm install`
3. removing all traces of node and reinstalling a different version

EDIT: project structure looks like

```
D:\temp\test-app
├── node_modules
├── index.js
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

Comment: What's your project structure like ? It doesn't automatically picks up index.js wherever it is

Comment: I updated the question. Both files are in one directory. `node index.js` doesn't throw an error though when I run it from `D:\temp\test-app`

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your `index.js` file to `server.js` and remove the `"start":` script entirely. Then `npm start` will work normally.

```
{
  "name": "test-app", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "", "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [], "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `npm run start` instead of `npm start` in the same directory as your `package.json`